# Django-503 App Maintenance Template Error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, settings, http-status-code-503

I recently downloaded coagulant's [Django-503](https://github.com/coagulant/django-503) app which generates a 503 page so that you can run maintenance.

The problem I am currently having is that I downloaded the app from GitHub and did a pip install. I followed all the instructions. However, when I try to turn on maintenance mode, I get the following error.

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000/admin/django_503/config/1/
Django Version:     1.4.3
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    admin_warning.html
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 138
```

Even though the package from GitHub came with the templates, Django can't seem to find them. Is there any possible solution to this?

Comment: @catherine thank you for taking the time to comment on this question. I posted my answer to this question below! take a look whenever you get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was, while doing a pip install, the package did not install the HTML files into the dist-packages directory where Django_503 resides. You need to manually add a templates folder inside Django_503 and then add the respective HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

Is the path containing admin_warning.html in your setting's [TEMPLATE_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#template-dirs)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @cmotley, I posted my answer below, I managed to figure it out, take a look.